# Is there any way to generate a unique code (like OTP) but not OTP

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to generate code automatically in my Flutter app, Then I want to share this automatically generated code with another person, and then they can be linked together. Like in a ludo game where a session is created.

Comment: Hi Aizan, Welcome to SO. your question is not showing any effort. Try yourself first and write some code to get better help. 
BTW, you can generate random number or hash Code and share with the other user.

Answer (score 1):

There is a flutter package [nanoid](https://pub.dev/packages/nanoid) to generate the random number for your app.
They also have a collision calculator depending on the number of users.

https://zelark.github.io/nano-id-cc/